# Rails dependent destroy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have `User` and `Organization` model. `User` `has_many :organizations` and `Organization` `has_many :users`.

When I want to destroy user from db using `@user.destroy` I get error `Key (id)=(3) is still referenced from table "organizations".`

Here is my User and Organization models:

Organization.rb

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged

  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :moderators, -> { where :members => { :role => 1 } }, :through => :members, :source => :user
  has_many :admins, -> { where :members => { :role => 2 } }, :through => :members, :source => :user
  has_many :campains, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :statuses, :as => :statusable
  has_many :activities
  has_many :world_members
  has_many :teams

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, :users
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :full_name, :use => :slugged
  acts_as_voter

  enum role: [:user, :moderator, :organization, :admin]

  has_many :members, :class_name => "Member", :foreign_key => "user_id", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :organizations, :through => :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id

  has_many :admin_organizations, ->{ where(members: {role: 2}) }, :through => :members, source: :organization
  has_many :moderate_organizations, ->{ where(members: {role: 1}) }, :through => :members, source: :organization
  has_many :member_organizations, ->{ where(members: {role: 0}) }, :through => :members, source: :organization

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, :organizations
```

Member.rb

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:member, :moderator, :admin]
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
```

Comment: remove the , :dependent => :destroy from has_many :members. Let the , :dependent => :destroy be only on has_many :organizations and has_many :users

Answer (score 0):

You should not have `dependent_destroy` for `:organizations` or `:users`, just for `:members`.

You do not have direct relation from organization to user, nor from user to organization.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizations, through: :members
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :organization
end
```

As you do not want to delete all users for example from an organization, just there reference to the organization and vice verse if you delete user, you do not want to delete all organizations on which user was connected to, just the reference

Comment: Then you have bad data from prior, this is working solution

Comment: I also thought that maybe I have bad data from prior, but I dont know how to resolve that without dropping db. Have you some advice?